# Set and access global variable

Tags: plugins, php, variables

I am learning plugin dev and modified this example snippet. I don't get why $myvar is empty in the my_plugin_action_handler function's scope.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: TEST Plugin
 */

global $myvar;
$myvar = false;



function myplugin_activate() {
    global $myvar;
    
    $myvar = true;
    error_log($myvar); // this will be 'whatever'
}

function my_plugin_action_handler(){
    global $myvar;
    if($myvar){
        error_log("Var true");
    }
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_plugin_action_handler');
```

Comment: You are only setting it to a value in the moment that you activate the plugin. All other times you're not setting it. Unless you have other code elsewhere that does it. Why are you using the plugin activation hook?

Comment: Global variables in PHP are not persistent across requests. You need to store the value in the database if that’s what you need.